# A question about dimension on exponential terms

Tags: integration, exponential-function, unit-of-measure

In an article I've studying, I have $f$, a function with unit $[\text{length}]^{-1}$, and the exponential $e^{\int_0^x f(s)d(s)}$, where $x$ is a length.

This exponential is a real number.

I'd like to understand better how could I drop there the units, because they are important from physical meaning.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you integrate with $\mathrm{d}s$, you're integrating over a length. Because of that, the unit of the result "as an area [under the curve]" is [length]$^{-1}$ (from $f$) times [length] (from $\mathrm{d}s$, or from $0$ to $x$ as a definite integral), so the result is dimensionless as required.

Exponentials, logarithms, and other things that aren't really finite applications of addition, multiplication, or fixed powers cannot handle units, and must have dimensionless inputs. Trig functions accept "radians" as dimensionless units.

Comment: Great answer, I thank you. And I have other doubt in this line: what about the limit $x$ (a lenght) to the integral...? I must consider it dimensionless?

Comment: You get an antiderivative of the form $F(s)$ which has dimensionless units. Then you evaluate, as a definite integral, the value $F(x)-F(0)$, which remains dimensionless.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. As soon the system open, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: In physical terms, the definite integral is more real - it's an actual area under the curve, which has the units of $x$-axis times the units of $y$-axis as required.

Comment: Thank you for this comment too, now the things are clearer

Comment: A final question, so I must have $f$ with unit $^{-1}$ of the limit, because the $ds$ must have same dimension of limit? This is the unique case for dimensionless input?

Comment: Not necessarily, since you might end up with double integrals and other fun stuff that could conceivably cancel all the units of $f$. For one integral, yes. The easiest way to me is just "integration is a fancier form of multiplication".

Comment: Thank you once again.